# SQL - Should I be killing connection after each query?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

1. I am using SQL for leader boards in a game.
2. I am new to databases.
3. I am communicating with my database through PHP
4. I am using Microsoft Azure free student account for my database/ hosting PHP

I am unsure how many connections my free account can handle and want to conserve traffic. This being said should I be killing my connection after each query, or does my setup automatically do this for the most part?

The reason I ask this is because I have made many queries (from one computer) and I figure if the connections stay open I would have run into problems thus far.

Comment: Please also review this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-overview/) that outlines some best practices for Azure SQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

You need not kill queries..When a query is done,the connection will be automatically closed and will be reached to connection pool..

You may have to worry about below limits based on your tier..

[image]

Further limits are documented here..

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-resource-limits/